# HighMap chart with lat long data

Tags: highmaps, angular2-highcharts

I am looking at the highmap from highcharts for angular 2 and looking at this demo:

http://plnkr.co/edit/AmDfKwhRhshFn3CPprkk?p=preview

Here, the series is like:

```
series : [{
    name: 'UTC',
    data: ['IE', 'IS', 'GB', 'PT'].map(function (code) {
        return { code: code };
    })
}, {
    name: 'UTC + 1',
    data: ['NO', 'SE', 'DK', 'DE', 'NL', 'BE', 'LU', 'ES', 'FR', 'PL', 'CZ', 'AT', 'CH', 'LI', 'SK', 'HU','SI', 'IT', 'SM', 'HR', 'BA', 'YF', 'ME', 'AL', 'MK'].map(function (code) {
        return { code: code };
    })
}, {
    name: 'UTC + 2',
    data: ['FI', 'EE', 'LV', 'LT', 'BY', 'UA', 'MD', 'RO', 'BG', 'GR', 'TR', 'CY'].map(function (code) {
        return { code: code };
    })
}, {
    name: 'UTC + 3',
    data: ['RU'].map(function (code) {
        return { code: code };
    })
}]
```

However, I want to provide coordindates (lat long) to plot the points. Is it possible to do this? If yes, how? Please note that I am looking for a solution specific to Angular 2

Answer (score 0):

If you can get your data in terms of latitudes and longitudes, it can be plotted on the map using the library `proj4js`. This library has to be included to work internally with `Highmaps`, need not do anything explicitly.

Your data has to be converted to latitude/longitude like you see here : http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/maps/demo/mappoint-latlon/

Check my other angular post here for a full working example in angular2+ versions: [Highmaps chart is empty in Angular 5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49600548/highmaps-chart-is-empty-in-angular-5)